# How to set the GOP(group of picture) of RDP on Windows Desktop?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, h.264

I found that the GOP length of RDP is 2592000 when I use gfx AVC444. I want to decrease this value.
How can I decrease this value on windows?
Here is h264 parse data.

```
0xcb 0xb2 0x13 0x92 0x98 0x73 0x43 0xda
    0xa8 0xa6 0xc7 0x42 0x98 0x35 0x6c 0xf5
    0x73 0x72 0x63 0x3a 0x33 0x20 0x68 0x3a
    0x39 0x32 0x38 0x20 0x77 0x3a 0x39 0x36
    0x30 0x20 0x66 0x70 0x73 0x3a 0x33 0x30
    0x2e 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x20 0x70 0x66 0x3a
    0x37 0x37 0x20 0x6c 0x76 0x6c 0x3a 0x39
    0x20 0x62 0x3a 0x30 0x20 0x62 0x71 0x70
    0x3a 0x33 0x20 0x67 0x6f 0x70 0x3a 0x32
    0x35 0x39 0x32 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x20 0x69
    0x64 0x72 0x3a 0x32 0x35 0x39 0x32 0x30
    0x30 0x30 0x20 0x73 0x6c 0x63 0x3a 0x34
    0x20 0x63 0x6d 0x70 0x3a 0x30 0x20 0x72
    0x63 0x3a 0x31 0x20 0x71 0x70 0x3a 0x32
    0x36 0x20 0x72 0x61 0x74 0x65 0x3a 0x32
    0x30 0x39 0x36 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x20 0x70
    0x65 0x61 0x6b 0x3a 0x30 0x20 0x62 0x75
    0x66 0x66 0x3a 0x37 0x38 0x36 0x30 0x30
    0x30 0x20 0x72 0x65 0x66 0x3a 0x33 0x20
    0x73 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3a 0x33 0x32 0x20
    0x61 0x73 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3a 0x31 0x20
    0x73 0x75 0x62 0x70 0x3a 0x31 0x20 0x70
    0x61 0x72 0x3a 0x36 0x20 0x33 0x20 0x33
    0x20 0x72 0x6e 0x64 0x3a 0x30 0x20 0x63
    0x61 0x62 0x61 0x63 0x3a 0x30 0x20 0x6c
    0x70 0x3a 0x32 0x20 0x63 0x74 0x6e 0x74
    0x3a 0x30 0x20 0x61 0x75 0x64 0x3a 0x31
    0x20 0x6c 0x61 0x74 0x3a 0x31 0x20 0x77
    0x72 0x6b 0x3a 0x31 0x20 0x76 0x75 0x69
    0x3a 0x31 0x20 0x6c 0x79 0x72 0x3a 0x31
    0x20 0x3c 0x3c 0x0
    string is ".....sC....B.5l.src:3 h:928 w:960 fps:30.000 pf:77 lvl:9 b:0 bqp:3 gop:2592000 idr:2592000 slc:4 cmp:0 rc:1 qp:26 rate:2096000 peak:0 buff:786000 ref:3 srch:32 asrch:1 subp:1 par:6 3 3 rnd:0 cabac:0 lp:2 ctnt:0 aud:1 lat:1 wrk:1 vui:1 lyr:1 <<."
```